# Execute method not getting covered

Tags: code-coverage

this is my batch in apex-

```
global class BatchEndTripReminder implements Database.batchable<sObject>,Database.stateful{ 
    global Map<Id,ExpenseManagement__c> ownerIdRecord; 
    global set<Id> ownerIds;
    global list<ExpenseManagement__c> expenseManageList;
    public BatchEndTripReminder(){
       expenseManageList = new list<ExpenseManagement__c>();

    }
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){

      return Database.getQueryLocator('select Date__c,Ownerid,id,DummyStage__c from ExpenseManagement__c where Date__c=TODAY and DummyStage__c!=\'end trip\'');
   }     
   global void execute(Database.BatchableContext info, List<ExpenseManagement__c> scope){
       system.debug('scope '+scope.size());
       expenseManageList.addAll(scope);

   }     
   global void finish(Database.BatchableContext info){
       List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new list<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
       for(ExpenseManagement__c temp:expenseManageList){
           Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
           system.debug('temp.ownerid '+temp.ownerid);
           mail.setTargetObjectId(temp.ownerid);
           //mail.setToaddresses(new String[]{'ajitesps@gmail.com'});
           mail.setSubject('Please end your trip for today!');
           String htmlBody =  '<html><body> <a href="'+URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/apex/dailyPlan" >Visit your check-in app</a></body></html>';
           mail.setHtmlBody(htmlBody);
           mail.saveAsActivity =false;
            emails.add(mail);           
       }
       Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
   } 
}
```

and this is the test class-

```
@IsTest
public class TestBatchEndTripReminder {
    public static testMethod void BatchEndTripReminder()
    {
        List<ExpenseManagement__c> expReceive = new List<ExpenseManagement__c>();
        for(integer i=0;i<200;i++){
            ExpenseManagement__c exp = new ExpenseManagement__c();
            exp.Name='TestExpense';
            exp.CurrencyIsoCode='INR';
            exp.Date__c=date.parse('10/7/2018');
            exp.DummyStage__c='start trip';
            expReceive.add(exp);
        }
        insert expReceive;
        System.Test.startTest();
        BatchEndTripReminder bdr = new BatchEndTripReminder();
        Database.executeBatch(bdr,200);
        System.Test.stopTest();     
    }
}
```

code coverage is 50% only the uncovered section is-

```
 global void execute(Database.BatchableContext info, List<ExpenseManagement__c> scope){
       system.debug('scope '+scope.size());
       expenseManageList.addAll(scope);

   }
```

and

```
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext info){
       List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new list<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
       for(ExpenseManagement__c temp:expenseManageList){
           Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
           system.debug('temp.ownerid '+temp.ownerid);
           mail.setTargetObjectId(temp.ownerid);
           //mail.setToaddresses(new String[]{'ajitesps@gmail.com'});
           mail.setSubject('Please end your trip for today!');
           String htmlBody =  '<html><body> <a href="'+URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/apex/dailyPlan" >Visit your check-in app</a></body></html>';
           mail.setHtmlBody(htmlBody);
           mail.saveAsActivity =false;
            emails.add(mail);           
       }
       Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before being concerned about code coverage, you should reconsider the use of `Database.Batchable`.

Your code just accumulates the batched `ExpenseManagement__c` objects and then process all of them in the `finish` method. This means that there is no benefit obtained and instead a lot of overhead added. If you do need the work to be done asynchronously, putting all the code in an `@future` method would be far simpler.

On the specific of the coverage, your test sets:

```
exp.Date__c=date.parse('10/7/2018');
```

but the query tests for:

```
Date__c=TODAY
```

so no rows will match. Changing the test to:

```
exp.Date__c = Date.today();
```

would fix that.